# string count method giving incorrect result

Tags: python, string, count

I have a strange problem with the following codewars Kata:

https://www.codewars.com/kata/51e056fe544cf36c410000fb/train/python

I haven't completed it, but I ran into a really strange problem with the string.count() method.

The count that I get with the method for word "an" is 8, eventhough it is only once in the string.

Advise would be much appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
import re

words = "In a village of La Mancha, the name of which I have no desire to call to \
mind, there lived not long since one of those gentlemen that keep a lance \
in the lance-rack, an old buckler, a lean hack, and a greyhound for \
coursing. An olla of rather more beef than mutton, a salad on most \
nights, scraps on Saturdays, lentils on Fridays, and a pigeon or so extra \
on Sundays, made away with three-quarters of his income."
# => ["a", "of", "on"]    

def top_3_words(text: str):
    text = re.sub('[^0-9a-zA-Z]+', ' ', text).strip(' ')
    arr = text.split(' ')
    dict = {value: text.count(value) for value in arr}

    result = []

    for _ in range(3):
        max_key = max(dict, key=dict.get)
        result.append(max_key)   
        dict.pop(max_key)
    print(result)

top_3_words(words)
```

Comment: `count` doesn't care about *words*, it just finds the *substring* "an", and that exists a few times in the string.

Comment: Bonus tip (not related to your problem): Do not use Python builtin names like `dict` as variable names; it's legal, but it's a dangerous habit and it will bite you sooner than you think.

Comment: thank you for the comments, I spotted my mistake. When creating the dictionary I used the text instead of using the array for the count. Makes now sense =)

Answer (score 0):

You should first tokenize string words and then count.

```
text = text.replace(',', '').split()
```

The above code return list of words in your string. Then you can count numbers of each word in the list.

Answer (score 0):

First split your string into individual words and count the number of `an` in it.

1. `temp_words = words.split(' ')`
2. `an_count = temp_words.count('an')`